# IBM Watson Concept Insights get related concepts (corpus) using cURL timing out

Tags: api, curl, ibm-watson, concept-insights

I am getting this error -> `{"code": 500, "message": "Forwarding error"}` every time I try to get related concepts from my private account and corpus.  The error seems to be a timeout error since it always dies at 2:30.

I've replaced the sample provided by IBM to point to my account and corpus.  Does anybody know why this is occurring?

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/corpora/accountid/corpus/related_concepts?limit=3&level=0"
```

cURL result

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0    44    0    44    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:30 --:--:--    10
```

Corpus status

```
{"id":"/corpora/accountid/corpus","documents":10,"last_updated":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","build_status":{"ready":10,"error":0,"processing":0}}
```

NOTE: I do not get this error if I use the public example provided by IBM on the API.  I have also masked my account id, corpus, username, and password for this public posting.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, since the error is corpus specific (since you mentioned you can the API to work on the public corpus), we would need to know more information about your corpus (like account id and corpus id) in order to help you out.

One way to allow you to provide this information privately is to open a ticket with the Bluemix system (there are 2 options described here)

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#support

If you list the "Watson Concept Insights" service in the ticket, we will get your information.